# Installing Python library from WHL file

Tags: python, installation

Skill level: beginner

I am trying to add a library in python. The extension is wheel.

Can somebody tell stepwise approach in installing wheel file?

Comment: See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel , install that package first (with pip &c), then follow its instructions.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 36):

First open a console then cd to where you've downloaded your file like some-package.whl and use

```
pip install some-package.whl
```

Note: if pip.exe is not recognized, you may find it in the "Scripts" directory from where python has been installed.  I have multiple Python installations, and needed to use the pip associated with Python 3 to install a version 3 wheel.

If pip is not installed, and you are using Windows: [How to install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

From [How do I install a Python package with a .whl file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file/27885547#27885547)
[sic],
How do I install a Python package USING a .whl file ?

For all Windows platforms:

1) Download the .WHL package install file.

2) Make Sure path [C:\Progra~1\Python27\Scripts] is in the system PATH string. This is for using both [pip.exe] and [easy-install.exe].

3) Make sure the latest version of pip.EXE is now installed.
At this time of posting:

> pip.EXE --version

```
  pip 9.0.1 from C:\PROGRA~1\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

4) Run pip.EXE in an Admin command shell.

```
 - Open an Admin privileged command shell.

 > easy_install.EXE --upgrade  pip

 - Check the pip.EXE version:
 > pip.EXE --version

 pip 9.0.1 from C:\PROGRA~1\Python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)

 > pip.EXE install --use-wheel --no-index 
     --find-links="X:\path to wheel file\DownloadedWheelFile.whl"
```

Be sure to double-quote paths or path\filenames with embedded spaces in them ! Alternatively, use the MSW 'short' paths and filenames.